# Redirecting only a specific page request for mobile users using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect requests for mobile users only to http://mydomain.com/video.html to http://mydomain.com/mobile/index.html using .htaccess

Currently it's a Wordpress site, so there is already some Wordpress stuff in my .htaccess file.

Here is what I have now:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Mobile redirect for the video 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

  # stuff to let through (ignore)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/mobile/" 
  RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
  #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/html/video.html.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/index.html [L,R=302]
</IFModule>
# END Mobile redirect
```

It is currently redirecting my iPad for all pages, and NOT for the page I want it to (video.html)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
# BEGIN Mobile redirect for the video 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # stuff to let through (ignore)
    RewriteRule ^mobile/ - [L]
    # redirect /video.html to /mobile/index.html for mobile browsers
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^video\.html$ /mobile/index.html [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
# END Mobile redirect
```

1. Because you have WordPress it will be better to place this block BEFORE WordPress block.

2. There is no real need for `# stuff to let through (ignore)` rule if you have so little rewrite rules in this block (especially if you place whole block before WordPress one). But since I do not know for sure how your website works, I leave it for you to test.

3. I see you are using `(.*)` pattern in RewriteRule .. and then one extra pattern in RewriteCond to do actual URL matching. No need -- you can do all of that in RewriteRule itself.

For example, this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/mobile/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

can easily be replaced by

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/ - [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried your solution, and now it's no longer redirecting anything at all. So it fixed one problem – that of redirecting every other page, but I still have the problem of getting it to redirect video.html to /mobile/index.html.

Comment: I should probably mention that I've tried the new block before and after the WordPress block with the same result, but have left it before now per your suggestion.

Comment: Additionally, in response to your #2, I had that line because without it, I get an Apache error for too many redirects. With that line in place, the redirect didn't repeat. Make sense?

Comment: OK - I got it working by using your code and commenting out this line:
     `# RewriteRule ^mobile/ - [L]`

I thought I needed it to prevent redirect looping. You were right. I didn't need it. Kudos and thank you.