# How do I rewrite/redirect a specific page just for mobile viewers to a external URL using .htcaccess?

Tags: redirect, mobile, joomla, url-rewriting

I wonder if it is possible to code in the .htcaccess file and make it redirect/rewrite to external url. It is a Joomla site.

What i want is that visitors with a mobile device such as phone or tablet should be redirected when they visit this page:
http://www.axima.se/index.php/nytt-a-begagnat/sok-begagnade-maskiner

This is the url that i want them to be directed to:
http://m.dealers.mascus.com/Axima

I found this thread, and used it for inspiration, tried some code-combination, but im not able to putting the code right together
[Redirecting only a specific page request for mobile users using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030301/redirecting-only-a-specific-page-request-for-mobile-users-using-htaccess)

This code is from the other thread (for a wordpress site) and im not sure what to keep and where to put my code:

```
# BEGIN Mobile redirect for the video 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # stuff to let through (ignore)
    RewriteRule ^mobile/ - [L]
    # redirect /video.html to /mobile/index.html for mobile browsers
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^video\.html$ /mobile/index.html [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
# END Mobile redirect
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$browser = JBrowser::getInstance();
if ($browser->isMobile() === true)
    echo "<p>Mobile website</p>";
else
    echo "<p>Standard website</p>";

echo "<p>More info on the user agent: </p>"; var_dump($browser);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using http://mobiledetect.net for that feature

at the top of mytemplate/index.php:

```
include 'pathtolibrary/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
$mob = JURI::base()."index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=mobile";
if ($detect->isMobile()) JFactory::getApplication()->redirect( $mob, $error, 'error' );
```

so you don't need to use htaccess.
you can see it on my site [www.menagenet.co.il](http://www.menagenet.co.il)

Comment: Joomla already has the capability of detecting the mobile. Why include and maintain another extra class?

Comment: Ok, sound reasonable, can you give a clue on how to do it using joomla's code ?